# How to correctly display characters from different languages?

Tags: c++, mysql, winapi, character-encoding

I am finishing application in Visual C++/Windows API and I am using MySql C Connector.

Whole application code uses ANSI, MySql C Connector is in ANSI too.

This program will be used on Polish and German computers with Windows XP/Vista/7 or 8.

I want to correcly display german umlauts and polish accent characters on:

- DialogBox controls (strings are loaded from language files)
- Generated XHTML documents
- Strings retrieved from MySql database displayed on controls and in XHTML documents

I have heard about MultiByteToWideChar and Unicode functions (MessageBoxW etc.), but application code is nearly finished, converting is a lot of work...

**How to make character encoding correctly with the least work and time?**

Maybe changing system code page for non-Unicode program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, of course: what code set is MySQL returning?  Or perhaps:
what code set was used when writing the data into the data base?

Other than that, I don't think you'll be able to avoid using 
either wide characters or multibyte characters: for single byte
characters, German would use ISO 8859-1 (code page 1252) or
ISO 8859-15, Polish ISO 8859-2 (code page 1250).  But what are
you doing with the characters in your own code?  You may be able
to get away with UTF-8 (code page 65001), without many changes.
The real question is where the characters originally come from
(although it might not be too difficult to translate them into
UTF-8 immediately at the source); I don't think that Windows
respects the code page for input.

Although it doesn't help you much to know it, you're dealing
with an almost impossible problem, since so much depends on
things outside your program: things like the encoding of the
display font, or the keyboard driver, for example.  In fact,
it's not rare for programs to display one thing on the screen,
and something different when outputting to the printer, or to
display one thing on the screen, but something different if the
data is written to a file, and read with another program.  The
situation is improving—modern Unix and the Internet are
gradually (very gradually) standardizing on UTF-8, everywhere
and for everything, and Windows normally uses UTF-16 for
everything that is pure Windows (but needs to support UTF-8 for
the Internet).  But even using the platform standard won't help
if the human client has installed (and is using) fonts which
don't have the characters you need.

Comment: When I write to MySql and retrieve with my program all characters are correct. When I write with phpMyAdmin but retrieve with program characters are not correct. But I don't know if on german Windows it will be correct too (I have only polish Windows). In MySql is utf8_bin.

Comment: @David For what definition of correct?  I presume MySQL is largely content neutral, at least for varchar fields.  So all programs will get back whatever was written.  But what is written isn't actually characters, but code points---small integer values.  The question is how the program which reads interprets those values.  If you write UTF-8, and the program which reads interprets the values as ISO 8859-1, it's not going to work.  Which is why I said that it's an almost impossible problem---unless you have absolute control of all elements in the chain.